# Even though I've declared my data types through pandas, the data is not showing up the way I would have hoped in the database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

For a project, I'm working on the datasets found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/restaurant-data-with-consumer-ratings)

I'm having trouble figuring out why some of the data isn't showing up the way I would have hoped it would in the database. (i.e., a categorical variable that should take on the numeric values of 0, 1, 2 are all showing up as null, even though every entry in the database takes on one of these three values)

```
ratings = pd.read_csv("data/rating_final.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1", dtype="unicode")
ratings["rating"] =  pd.Categorical(ratings["rating"], categories = [0, 1, 2], ordered=False)
ratings["food_rating"] = pd.Categorical(ratings["food_rating"],     categories = [0, 1, 2], ordered=False)
ratings["service_rating"] = pd.Categorical(ratings["service_rating"], categories = [0, 1, 2], ordered=False)`
```

I'm more than happy to explain my logic with the code, but the rating_final.csv is a .csv file from the Kaggle dataset, and the encoding is something special to the way data is encoded when it is put onto Kaggle.

Another issue I'm having is when I declare a variable of type float, it is still showing me the int values and cutting the end part of the decimal off. For example, 1.67 is being shown to me as 1 when I query the database. I'm not exactly sure what to do in this case, and this is my first time working with pandas so I want to make sure I get this right.

Comment: You set the dataframe to Unicode, but then set the categorical values with a list of integers `[0,1,2]`

Comment: @djk47463 What would I encode it with instead? I've only ever used unicode for that part so I'm not too sure what to do.